# Logic Error: The left operand of '&' is a garbage value

Tags: iphone, ios5, mgtwitterengine

I used Twitter-OAuth-iPhone to synchronize the message in my app. It's all right in iOS4. 
After upgraded to **iOS5**, choose menu **'Product' > 'Analyze'**, and got a few warnings.

In **NSData+Base64.m**, It's warning '**The left operand of '&' is a garbage value**'
[image]

Codes here:

```
if( ixinbuf == 4 ) {
ixinbuf = 0;
outbuf [0] = ( inbuf[0] << 2 ) | ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x30) >> 4 );
outbuf [1] = ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x0F ) << 4 ) | ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x3C ) >> 2 );
outbuf [2] = ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x03 ) << 6 ) | ( inbuf[3] & 0x3F );

for( i = 0; i < ctcharsinbuf; i++ ) 
    [mutableData appendBytes:&outbuf[i] length:1];
}
```

And there are other error message:
[image: error]

Sorry I am a novice and have no any clue about these problems.
Would you help me fix it please?
Many THANKS!

Edit------------
Logic loop screenshot:

*removing dead ImageShack link*

Full Codes: https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/blob/master/Twitter+OAuth/MGTwitterEngine/NSData+Base64.m

Thanks any suggestion!

Comment: Click on the message and it will show you where the garbage value comes from. (Post a screenshot if you still need help.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

sidestep it by initializing inbuf to an empty char array:

```
unsigned char inbuf[4] = {};
unsigned char outbuf[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh, *very* nice.

What Clang is telling you here is that, under some very specific circumstances, you may end up never initializing `inbuf[1]`. I believe this might happen for input which looked something like:

```
a=
```

There's another major issue being pointed out here -- the sizes of `inbuf` and `outbuf` are swapped. Should be `char inbuf[4], outbuf[3]`, not vice versa.

Comment: Thank you @duskwuff. I've changed line 35 from 'unsigned char inbuf[3], outbuf[4];' to 'unsigned char inbuf[4], outbuf[3];'.The yellow warning disappeared(great!). But the logic errors is still displayed. Any more hints?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a if statement to ensure that the `inbuf[x]` has some value in it

```c
if (sizeof(inbuf[1]) > 0x1)
    outbuf [0] = ( inbuf[0] > 4 );
if (sizeof(inbuf[2]) > 0x1)
    outbuf [1] = ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x0F ) > 2 );
if (sizeof(inbuf[3]) > 0x1)
    outbuf [2] = ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x03 )
```

I'm not sure though if it's "fool proof".